# Как создавать перегруженные методы/функции в сервисе для репозитория

Tags: c#, .net, проектирование

Предположим имеется следующий класс:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public bool Gender {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

public UserService
{
    readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public UserService(IRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    //Функция возвращающая всех пользователей
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _userRepository.Table.ToList();
    }
}
```

Предположим мне необходимо наложить некие ограничения на возвращаемых пользователей, пусть будет возраст и пол, тогда я создам такую функцию:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(int age, bool gender)
{
    return _userRepository.Table
        .Where(x=>x.Age==age&&x.Gender==gender)
        .ToList();
}
```

А если понадобится фильтровать по какому либо другому набору полей, не создавать же *100500* таких методов/функций, ведь они могут с собой и пересекаться и тогда явно будет дублирование кода.

Данные `User`, `UserService` приведены для примера, все совпадения с действительностью не специальны.

Хочется узнать как необходимо создавать *перегруженные* методы/функции.

Comment: odata смотрели?

Comment: @Stack нет, если честно я даже не знаю о чем сейчас Вы

Comment: _"я даже не знаю о чем сейчас"_ -- про третий вариант из выбранного ответа, где сказано _"вы работаете с веб-сервисом ... вы можете принимать список IDictionary<string, object>"_ -- вместо списка используется OData и язык запросов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это тот момент, когда стоит задуматься, какие у вас абстракции и почему. Как у вас хранятся данные на самом деле?

1. Положим, на самом деле вы работаете с **голым списком прямо в памяти**. В этом случае достаточно принимать `Func<User, bool> filter` и передавать его в `Enumerable.Where` как есть.
2. Положим, на самом деле вы работаете с **базой данных**. В этом случае вы можете принимать `Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter` и передавать его в `Queryable.Where` как есть.
3. Положим, на самом деле вы работаете с **веб-сервисом**. В этом случае вы можете принимать список `IDictionary<string, object>` с именами свойств и значениями, передавать его сервису, сервис может строить или компилировать соответствующее выражение (в зависимости от того, что в нём на самом деле: вариант 1 или 2).

   Если требуются более сложные условия, чем проверка на равенство, нужно смотреть, фильтры какой сложности требуется поддерживать, и искать компромиссы.

Возможно, сейчас я услышу возражения: "Но мне же нужно супер-универсальное сверх-модульное архи-заменяемое решение!" Нет, оно вам не нужно. YAGNI!

Вы никогда не скроете факта, что все три варианта работают с совершенно разной скоростью, имеют разные ограничения и так далее. Нет никакого "общего случая", это миф. Поэтому не изобретайте сложности там, где они вам не нужны. А они вам не нужны практически никогда.

Скажите, зачем вам понадобился "сервис", если уже есть "репозиторий"? Вам действительно нужен лишний слой абстракций?

Comment: `Repository<T>` у меня описывает базовый функционал, такой как: `Create`,`Read`,`Update`,`Delete`, в `Service` у меня логика получения данных(`Join()` ну и т.п.). вопрос то собственно был, как перегружают методы в целом, а не в конкретном случае с репозиторием

Comment: @Bald56rus Вы сейчас пытаетесь запрятать поглубже Table, и практического смысла в этом, скорее всего, не очень много. Просто выставите IQueryable наружу и делайте любые запросы. Если запрос будет повторяться — засунтье его в сервис. Вы пытаетесь придумать интерфейс, не зная, как вы реально собираетесь его использовать. / Ну а про "общий случай" я уже всё сказал, его не бывает.

Comment: Использование generic repository дает мне возможность в любой момент с малой кровью заменить бд, на текущий момент я использую *Entity Framework* и *SQL Express*, т.е. у меня есть класс который реализует обобщенный `IRepository<T>`, если мне необходимо будет изменить хранилище я реализую другой класс. на текущий момент я строю(пытаюсь) архитектуру следующего вида: DAO,DAL,BLL,GUI, gui не работает с базой напрямую, взаимодействие происходит через слой сервисов(BLL) который предоставляет методы возвращающие DTO

Comment: раньше же я писал так как вы и советуете без излишних абстракций, есть *gui* и все выполняется в нем, запросы к бд, и запросы я писал сначала так: `select * from table where col1={1}`, потом *эволюционировал* на использование `SqlParameter`, сейчас вот дорос до ORM и рекомендаций как строить архитектуру что бы не было так больно при её дальнейшей поддержке

Comment: @Bald56rus, но советы Дискорда нисколько не мешают абстракциям

Comment: @Discord сервис у топикастера, насколько я понял - это фасад BL. Т.е. когда вы говорите ему - уберите сервис и оставьте вместо него торчащим наружу IQueryable - вы говорите "высуньте IQueryable в UI, и делайте оттуда запросы" :)

Answer (score 6):

> А если понадобится фильтровать по какому либо другому набору полей, не
>   создавать же 100500 таких методов/функций, ведь они могут с собой и
>   пересекаться и тогда явно будет дублирование кода.

Отложенное выполнение - то что вам надо.
Если сделать вот так, то всегда можно сделать отложенный расчет логики.

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return _userRepository.Table.AsQueryable();
}
```

Стоит учитывать, что иногда для запроса `GetUsers().Where(u => u.Age > 20)` можно спокойно вызывать `Sum\Count\Show`, а иногда лучше явно материализовать запрос (добавить `.ToList()`), чтобы не дергать базу несколько раз.

Для частых кейсов всегда можно завернуть в функцию:

```
public static IQueryable<User> GetActiveUsers()
{
  return GetUsers().Where(u => u.IsActive);
}
```

либо просто фильтр:

```
public static IQueryable<User> WhereUsersActive(IQueryable<User> users)
{
  return users.Where(u => u.IsActive);
}
```

можно ещё экстеншном, если хочется:

```
public static IQueryable<User> WhereUsersActive(this IQueryable<User> users)
{
  return users.Where(u => u.IsActive);
}
```

Comment: про материализацию это понятно, просто не всегда имеет смысл тащить все из бд на клиент, мне больше подходит вариант предложеный @Discord: `public IEnumerable GetUsers(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter)` в качестве перегруженного метода. а так за `Table` как раз и скрывается `IQueryable`. спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Bald56rus для пачки ограниченных вариантов - может и годится, главное не начать плодить их пачками под каждый кейс.

Answer (score 4):

Репозиторий и сервис не нужны. Вы не должны пытаться заранее определить, какие запросы к данным вам понадобятся, да это и не получится. Тысяча функций на все случаи жизни в репозитории — чистый дубляж кода, они обычно не несут особого смысла.

`IEnumerable<T>` или `IQueryable<T>` — достаточно мощная абстракция. Вы сможете (относительно) легко поменять базу данных. (Проблемы «протекающих абстракций» всё равно останутся — например, если новая база плохо делает какие-нибудь операции.) И вы сможете легко выразить производные операции, отталкиваясь от списка, LINQ вполне подходит для этого.

---

Уточнение: `IQueryable<T>` — абстракция уровня *модели*. То, что необходимо выставлять UI-уровню из VM, это не `IQueryable<Т>`, а коллекция VM-объектов (для вашего случая — `UserVM`). Скорее всего, вам необходимо будет при переходе к VM-объектам ограничить (пользователю никогда не хочется видеть миллион юзеров, он столько в голове не удержит) и материализовать список сущностей, а не выставлять голый `queryable.Select(user => new UserVM(user))`, иначе каждый чих в UI будет дёргать базу.

Comment: я уже понял что лучше оставить торчащим наружу `IQueryable<T>` в сервисном слое, а по мере необходимости дублирующийся код переносить в соответствующий слой(Service)

Comment: т.е. Вы за то что бы использовать контекст `ef` напрямую в gui? раз не нужен ни сервис ни репозиторий? или я не правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Нет, не контекст EF, а `IQueryable<User>`.

Comment: @Bald56rus И не в UI, конечно. UI-объекты и сущности базы данных — совершено отдельные вещи.

Comment: Вам нужен ещё `UserVM` с INPC, по идее. Но это не имеет отношения к модели, которой и принадлежит репозиторий и база.

Comment: @VladD сервис у топикастера, насколько я понял - это фасад BL. Т.е. когда вы говорите ему - уберите сервис и оставьте вместо него торчащим наружу IQueryable - вы говорите именно "высуньте IQueryable в UI"

Comment: @PashaPash: Разделение модели и VM нужно в любом случае. (ТС и я обсудили это где-то в чате, ЕМНИП.)

Comment: @VladD я тоже с ним это обсуждал. сервисы у него - это фасады BL. так что у вас в ответе буквально написано "высовывайте IQueryable из BL, отдавайте модель базы напрямую в presentation". как и в ответе Discord с пачкой плюсов и зеленой галкой :(

Comment: @PashaPash: Мой ответ скорее на формально заданный вопрос — я понимал сервис как чисто модельную штуку. Хотя да, надо бы написать уточнение.

Comment: @PashaPash: Написал.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на самом деле зависит от того, что подразумевается под "сервисом".

Если под сервисом подразумевается что-то, что будет вызываться изнутри бизнес логики - то да, в этом виде он абсолютно излишен. Единственный плюс в таком "сервисе" - он, возможно, чуть-чуть облегчает юнит-тестирование, ценой отказа от IQueryable.

Но если под сервисом подразумевается фасад BL-уровня, т.е. вызываться методы этого сервиса будут из UI/Presentation, то сервис в таком виде *должен* существовать:

- он прячет IQueryable от Presentation, не давая бизнес-логике выползти в код UI.
- он *должнен*, по возможности преобразовывать модели BL в Local DTO - модели, отвязанные от базы, и пригодные для представления.
- он должен очерчивать время жизни бизнес-операций (контролировать время жизни контекста / unit of work) - этому сейчас мешает лишний Generic Repository.
- он должен контролировать fetch plan - не давать бизнес-логике уйти в n+1.

Предложения выбросить фасад (сервис) в таком случае - это, практически, предложение делать запросы в базу напрямую из UI, что является чистейшим злом :)

Посмотрите официальный гайд [Microsoft Application Architecture Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx), раздел Business Layer Guidelines. Паттерн, который вы пытаетесь реализовать сервисом, называется Application Façade, его предназначение

> Centralize and aggregate behavior to provide a uniform service layer.

Т.е. он делает именно то, что делает ваш сервис - прячет от UI особенности работы бизнес-логики. Он прячет сам факт существования базы, возможности фильтровать пользователей, особенности выборки - и оставляет тупой интерфейс для UI - отдать параметры, получить пользователей.

И в таком случае - ответ на вопрос "как создавать методы" - достаточно очевиден: Интерфейс фасада должен соответствовать потребностям вызывающего его кода UI. А не следовать возможностям фильтрации или каким-то особенностям бизнес операций.

Если UI нужно выбрать пользователя по последней букве фамилии - у вас в фасаде должен быть метод "ВыбратьПоПоследнейБуквеФамилии". Если UI не нужен метод "получить всех пользователей" - то и в фасаде его быть не должно.

Comment: Ну, такая штука как `ВыбратьПоПоследнейБуквеФамилии` нужна, как мне кажется, только с бедными фреймворками типа WinForms. Для WPF, например, UI дёргает команду → VM вызывает в фоне получение нужного `queryable.OrderBy(...).Take(...).ToList()` → меняется коллекция в VM → подхватывается UI-ем через Binding → профит.

Comment: @VladD это синтетический пример для совсем крайнего случай - тот, который "нельзя угадать заранее, пока заказчик не попросит". и у топикастера asp.net, там свои заморочки )

Comment: Ну, и тут тоже можно по идее сколотить подобие `INotifyCollectionChanged` через WebSocket?

Comment: @VladD нет, это неэффективно, и требует подключения вебсокета к тому же физическому серверу, на который пришел основной запрос (а это еще надо как-то организовать). вызовы из клиента (из скрипта) и так асинхронны, так что синхронная обработка на сервере или асинхронная - без разницы. т.е. даже если там реально будет написано ВыбратьПоПоследнейБуквеФамилии - клиент все равно получит аккуратный асинхронный коллбек с данными, как будто все было сделано через INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: @VladD т.е. это старый добрый Client-Server с постоянным соединением, от него практически везде отказались. Даже вебсокеты используют чаще для односторонних нотификаций (так, как это сделано на SO, например). Есть типовые исключения - чат, например. Но это именно исключения.

Comment: Хм. А если мы хотим добавлять строки «ответа» автоматически, как только они появятся? Как например на SO [полу]автоматически появляются новые вопросы. Такое сработает?

Comment: @VladD сработает - но это именно односторонняя связь - т.е. она инициируется сервером, на основе действий других пользователей (или своих, но в другом табе). Ответ же на свои собственные действия всегда приходит напрямую, а не через вебсокеты.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно вынести параметр делегата фильтрации из Where в параметр функции
как то так:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(Func<User,bool> filter)
{
    return _userRepository.Table
        .Where(filter)
        .ToList();
}
```

и использовать как `var users = GetUsers(x=>x.Age==age&&x.Gender==gender);`

P.S. Если в целом [Руководство по C# --- Перегрузка методов](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level6/6_1.php)

Comment: Предостережение: если за Table скрывается какой-нибудь IQueryable, то подобный код вытащит всю таблицу в память.

Comment: В начале статьи, на которую вы дали ссылку сказано:  "Перегрузка методов относится к одному из способов реализации полиморфизма в C#." Это абсурд. Перегрузка методов не имеет никакого отношения к полиморфизму в ООП.

Comment: См. "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" 1994 года. Авторы: Эрих Гамма, Ральф Джонсон и др.

Comment: @klutch1991 Перегрузка методов относится к ad-hoc полиморфизму [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.28ad_hoc.29_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.BC)

Comment: @ApInvent, ad-hoc-полиморфизм не применяется в ОО-языках.

Comment: @klutch1991 это Вы где встретили такие ограничения?

Comment: @ApInvent, я не говорил "нельзя применять", я сказал "не применяется". Какой смысл применять ad-hoc в мультипарадигменном объектно-ориентированном языке (таком как C#), если в нём в полной мере реализованы основные парадигмы ООП, что позволяет использовать первую форму полиморфизма. В императивных языках (таких как Pascal), это может быть полезным.

Comment: @ApInvent, да и вообще, на Вашем месте я бы не принимал wiki за единственную истину, а вот фундаментальные труды GoF, пожалуй, являются общепризнанным стандартом. Полистайте книгу, в ней дано чёткое определение полиморфизма.

Comment: @klutch1991 ad-hoc полиморфизм, а именно перегрузка методов, дает возможность использовать различную реализацию для различных типов в отличие от параметрического полиморфизма (если его Вы назвали первой формой полиморфизма). Что на счет wiki - та статья базируется на не менее фундаментальных трудах список которых приведен в ее конце.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращать "голые" IEnumerable<> или IQueryable<> "не есть хорошо", поскольку вы сливаете потребителю вашего класса всё и пусть он сам разбирается с этим. Этим вы нарушаете разделение на слои вашего приложения, поскольку в этом случае возвращаемое вами значение может быть проброшено далеко вверх по слоям.

Но, как всегда для этого есть решение. Называется "Спецификация": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern

Придуман данный шаблон Эриком Эвансом и подробно описан в его книге.

Вот ещё пример реализации: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670115/Specification-pattern-in-Csharp

Comment: Это то же, что экспортировать наружу `IQueryable`, только с ужасным тяжеловесным синтаксисом. И вам придётся определить все «бизнес-правила» заранее и ad hoc, что практически никогда не работает.

Comment: @VladD Не согласен. Это совсем не тоже, что экспортировать 'IQueryable'. Подход спецификации тестируем в отличие от 'IQueryable'. Правила и способ их применения строго регламентирован. Их не обязательно и не нужно все придумывать заранее, а появляться они будут по мере необходимости. Да, со временем будет целый ворох мелких спецификаций, но в этом случае надо провести анализ, выявив наиболее крупные ассоциаций и сделать рефакторинг, объединив в более крупные спецификации. А в некоторых случаях, когда один набор спецификаций нужен часто, лучше сразу в сервисе сделать соответствующий метод.

Comment: Не думаю, что есть особенный смысл в тестировании методов типа `queryable.Single(u.id == id).Posts` (а именно такими по сути будут ваши методы), вы фактически будете тестировать LINQ. При этом вы потеряете комбинируемость, и при малейшем изменении на уровне UI вам придётся добавлять новый метод в сервис. Получится сильная связность: сервис будет писаться под нужды конкретного UI. А если вы таки проведёте анализ и рефакторинг, вы получите заново изобретённый LINQ в лучшем случае (потому что LINQ и есть правильная декомпозиция).

Comment: Спецификация не для тривиальных методов типа `queryable.Single(u.id == id).Posts`. Это излишнее упрощение. Для этого есть методы `GetById`. Они для создания более сложных выборок: `repo.Get(maleUsersSpec.And(ageBetween20and30.Or(ageOver50)).And(subscribedToNews))`.

Comment: Заметьте, кстати, насколько такие методы тривиально делаются на LINQ, и насколько много вам придётся кодировать специфических мелочей наподобие `ageOver51`, `ageBetween28And33` и `numberOfPostsNearChristmasIsPositiveForAtLeastTwoLastYears`.